# Visualize results by Tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have a list that each element composed of 4 entries - episode, reward,exploration_rate, and running average. I want to visualize the results by the Tensorboard. 
There is some way to visualize these results? 
It should be mentioned that I already have the results, so I cant use Callbacks. Currently, I have the results as a Matplotlib plot (Presented in the figure). However, I want to use TensorBoard.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: [This link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/image_summaries) might help

Answer (score 0):

Start by activating your environment in which tensorflow is installed.

```
conda activate <tensorflow_env>
```

Then, follow the below command by passing your "log_directory" as the parameter

```
tensorboard --logdir <log directory>
```

Kindly follow the link

```
 https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/image_summaries
```